# Make blink(1) blink a specific color

Tags: command-line, blink1

I'm playing with my new [`blink(1)`](http://thingm.com/products/blinkm), and trying to hook it's command line interface into some of my programs, but the docs are a little limited and I'm struggling to figure out how to run even some seemingly simple commands.

In particular, the CLI docs say:

```
Usage: 
  blink1-tool <cmd> [options]
where <cmd> is one of:
  ....
  --blink <numtimes>          Blink on/off
  ....
```

So I try to run `blink1-tool --blink 5` and it outputs `blink 5 times rgb:0,0,0:` and doesn't light up.

How do I use the `--blink` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the fact that `blink1-tool --blink 5` doesn't do anything is a bug.  Originally `--blink` just blinked white, but a [recent fix](https://getsatisfaction.com/thingm/topics/blink1_tool_blink_option_feature) allows you to specify the color to blink (the usage script hasn't been updated yet).

The correct syntax for `--blink` is now:

```
blink1-tool [options] --rgb r,g,b --blink num
```

Note that `[options]` come before `<cmd>` despite the message in the usage script.

For example, to blink purple on for a second, off for a second, taking a fifth of a second to transition, you would run:

```
blink1-tool -t 1000 -m 200 --rgb 255,0,255 --blink 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set the `--rgb` switch before `--blink`

This is valid:

> blink1-tool -t 1000 -m200 --rgb 255,0,255 --blink 5

This is not valid:

> blink1-tool -t 1000 -m200 --blink 5 --rgb 255,0,255

Comment: Correct.  Despite the `--` notation suggesting order-independence, `--rgb` must come before `--blink`.